# Unable to install postsharp on VS 2017

Tags: postsharp

I have both VS 2017 and VS team explorer 2017 installed. 
it keeps saying prerequisites are missing

https://gm1.ggpht.com/5Cr-ZEa-WXgI7T6p3jyg7_LdpUI6IbQMBe4nPIRnFiMn6h254v2XD3nfiSpMrzHP9fHUt1GTSoI4oiuK7c_-00w1Q4aqfm_pomAVhNxGEmVhYsNRBw1z_C6BAGva3L-yfNOgUaZPXfkeP4A7IhJj_XQ-Ffa_KV3u7BngBbp7TZBoqvbFazByShPEnkRlo0pYpYnKDVYGqalM64tSshsDxBUGKrrx4jf9aQNkG-z6vdyg-iAN9NwDQavGFlE5bP_ggHqTWIZWTjLZIll_wm5aYYf5ctkZuux9Mo66XiJU6fRkhzy_ykkiBcxBjlY_Gw3_gx9FWPsSXC7xNEbDemaOaCvVMTjGlhwPel1VuCSQS5qvCv2k-5aQ7xgcKibKDnXszGUwaaXSXHDPlHYaJHVLN87gVau1mrlhgNLctaPJ3UJcqty6377VCmHDUrcQZFpiLzZE4uGII7VmUJG3fKZVBL3So5kDijzPi5Jx1BmpE5ojgS2rwCUR9HdEprBxBBrJATSTKLKUob1cztCsNIZ5AJt9EEUDSrzcWj6uVcbT5sf5evkHxD4B94OWTZLBiLLwW06RBrTejNvBFgSBJNRz7f5cFyjipPOT-dKqD8DUzSjL4FYS9w27gSkrFvnUGN_D689YscyEEh2hyc9O6n45Q2OaIdPDgxY_NKb1cCuA-RS6CQ0GQ0pWMjHLsOQi=w1088-h374-l75-ft

Comment: I have the same problem installing PostSharp on VS 2017 Enterprise because I have VS 2017 **Test** Professional installed. PostSharp installer complains about prerequisites for **Test** Professional and can not be installed at all.

Comment: yeah.. I don't seem to be able to find a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed in PostSharp 5.0.35.